# How to write two lists of different length to column and row in csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have two lists of different length:

```
list1 = ['a']
list2 = [['apple','banana','grapes']]
```

What I want in the csv is the following:

```
col1  col2
a     apple, banana, grapes
```

So first I tried `itertool` and `izip`, but it seems to put only first element of list in the list2 in col2, so it looks like:

```
col1  col2
a     apple
```

How can I get the version above, with complete list in list2 as rows?

I used the following code to store the above to csv:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(izip(list1,sum(list2,[]))
```

Comment: The `,` in CSV means delimiter by default, I fear if you need to store `1,2,3,4` as `1;2;3;4` or `"1,2,3,4"`, Can you attach the piece of code you are using to write in csv file ?

Comment: @ZdaR so I should convert list2 as string?

Comment: Yeah exactly, if that suits your need

Comment: @ZdaR I added the code, it's simply using izip to store to lists into csv

Comment: Does `list1` always contain the same number of elements as `list2`? Are there always only strings in `list1` and lists of numbers in `lists2`?

Comment: @Cleb For the fist question, yes, for the second question, no - in my actual data both are strings

Comment: Is there still something missing/not working? There are now four answers that all solve your problem, so it would be nice if you accepted one of those by clicking at the green check next to the preferred answer to show others that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

`izip` will chop the longer list to match the shorter one, so `izip(['a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])` actually gives `['a', 'a']`, that is where the problem comes from.

Also generally you would want to  use `str.join()` instead of `sum()` to convert a list to a string.

From the question I guess you want a csv file delimited by tabs. To solve the problem, first convert `list2` to a list of strings:

```
    >>> list2_str = [','.join(lst) for lst in list2]
    ['apple,banana,grapes']
```

Then zip `list1` and `list2_str`:

```
    >>> list3 = zip(list1, list2_str)
    [['a', 'apple,banana,grapes']]
```

Open a csv writer with 'excel-tab' dialect and write the rows:

```
    >>> writer = csv.writer(file, dialect='excel-tab')
    >>> writer.writerows(list3)
```

If instead you want a csv file with ',' as delimiter, simply remove the `dialect` parameter. Python will correctly quote the second column, producing

```
    a,"apple,banana,grapes"
```

in the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas` doing something similar to the following:

```
list1 = ['a']
list2 = [['apple','banana','grapes']]
import pandas as pd
f = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list1, 'col2':list2})
f.to_csv('filename.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ZdaR pointed out in the comments, commas are the default separator in `.csv` files, thus, storing your strings separated by a comma might lead to confusion. Instead, you could store your strings separated by a semicolon.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b']

list2 = [['apple','banana','grapes'], ['foo', 'bar']]

# convert all your lists of strings to single strings separated by a semicolon
list3 = [";".join(li) for li in list2]
```

`list3` looks then as follows:

```
['apple;banana;grapes', 'foo;bar']
```

Now you can use your code:

```
from itertools import izip
import csv

with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(izip(list1, list3))
```

which gives you the following output

```
a   apple;banana;grapes
b   foo;bar
```

If you then want to read the file back in again you can do this easily using e.g. pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('some.csv', header=None, names=['col1', 'col2'])
```

which gives you:

```
 col1                 col2
0    a  apple;banana;grapes
1    b              foo;bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach depends on if you really want only two columns or more?

If extra columns are required:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

list1 = ['a', 'b']
list2 = [['apple','banana','grapes'], ['cherry']]

with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["col1", "col2"])

    for i1, i2 in izip(list1, list2):
        writer.writerow([i1] + i2)
```

This would give you:

```
col1,col2
a,apple,banana,grapes
b,cherry
```

If only two columns are needed, you could switch to using tab characters for your delimiters to allow the commas to separate the `list2` entries:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

list1 = ['a', 'b']
list2 = [['apple','banana','grapes'], ['cherry']]

with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(["col1", "col2"])

    for i1, i2 in izip(list1, list2):
        writer.writerow([i1] + [', '.join(i2)])
```

This would give you:

```
col1    col2
a   apple, banana, grapes
b   cherry
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause problems when one reads the csv in again? When I try `df=pd.read_csv('some.csv')`, the resulting dataframe looks rather strange. How would you read your csv?